# Cant get access to variable inside function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to access a variable inside a function. 
Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="box1" class="box" onclick="set(1)"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
let i = 0;

function set(number){
i = number;
}

console.log(i);
```

**Console Log Output: [When i click my div]**

```
undefined
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: not sure why it would log anything when you click the div

Comment: Would'nt the function recieve the paramater and set i to the paramater?

Comment: Is your console.log firing before you click on the div?

Comment: You code does not log `undefined` (instead it outputs `0`, immediately on page load).

Comment: Javascript variables do not persist through the lifecycle of the program like that. They will if say you are using Angular and are using $scope variables. But, you will not be able to set a global variable and then access it on subsequent calls.

Comment: "But, you will not be able to set a global variable and then access it on subsequent calls." — Yes you can! What you can't do is access a value *before* you set it.

Comment: @LukeBecker That is not correct at all.  If you define a global variable, you can access it in any later function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Console Log Output: [When i click my div]

No.

The only time you call `console.log` it will output `0` and that is the log output **before** you click the div.

If you want to get the output **when** you click the div then the `console.log` statement must be **inside** the event handler function.

Comment: This is why a love stackoverflow! Thank you!